# What are we doing?

Tags: riddle, word

> When it happens to me, I scold the offender.
>
> When I take one intentionally, I'm satisfied.
>
> When I do this unintentionally, I hurt.
>
> Everyone does this on purpose.

**What are we doing?**

**What do we do this to intentionally?**

**What do we do this to unintentionally?**

Hint:

> When it happens *to me*, stitches may be in order!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> bite

When it happens to me, I scold the offender.

> dont bite me. I don't want my wife to see the hickey!

When I do this intentionally, I'm satisfied.

> Eat! That steak tasted great

When I do this unintentionally, I hurt.

> Ouch! bit my tongue

Most people do this on purpose several times a day.

> eat, bite, chew

Hint:

> When it happens to me, stitches may be in order!

Answer to hint:

> Bad dog, you hurt me that time

Comment: Gah...  Just wrote this out to have to delete it again.  +1

Answer (score 3):

> scratching, maybe?

When it happens to me, I scold the offender.

> When a cat scratches you, with it's claws

When I do this intentionally, I'm satisfied.

> Aah, yes, scratching yourself when it itches feels good !

When I do this unintentionally, I hurt.

> You might even bleed, depending on what you scratch yourself on

Most people do this on purpose several times a day.

> well, I sure do !

When it happens to me, stitches may be in order!

> Yes, if you wounded yourself, or if that thrice-cursed cat made a tear in your favourite sweater ..

Comment: I like this answer, but I know a lot of people who don't scratch!

Comment: Give it another shot- I rephrased the riddle for clarity.

Comment: A person who don't scratch is a person who scratches when no one is looking ;)

Answer (score 3):

Building off [Den's answer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/35636/12700), I think you are talking about

> cuts?

When it happens to me, I scold the offender.

> When someone **cuts** in line in front of me, I make it a point to berate the insensitive jerk.

When I take one intentionally, I'm satisfied.

> When I broker a deal, I make sure I take a **cut** for my troubles.

When I do this unintentionally, I hurt.

> When I **cut** myself unintentionally, it causes pain and bleeding.

Everyone does this on purpose several times a day.

> Everybody **cuts** into their food everyday.

When it happens to me, stitches may be in order!

> A deep or long cut may require stitches to heal properly.

Comment: You are *so close*.